# How to access the HttpContext.Application other than Controller class ie.Outside of the Controlle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the below Controller class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Index(CustomerModel model)
    {               
         Validate.ValidateModel(model);

            HttpContext.Application["IsAppIdAvailable"];
            return View();
    } 
}
```

and I have a Validate.cs class file like below

```
public class Validate   
{       
    public static void Test()       
    {
        if(Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Application["IsAppIdAvailable"]))
        {
             //Just assume this senario
             return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In the test method of the Validate class we are not able to access the `HttpContext.Application` but we are able to access the `HttpContext.Application` in the `HomeController`.

I understand the `HomeController` inherit from `Controller` class because of that `HttpContext.Application` has value.

Is there anyway I can access the `HttpContext.Application` in a class which does not inherit `Contoller` class. Please help

Comment: Are you using dependency injection? Try to stay away from coupling your code to HttpContext directly. Abstract away the functionality you want and inject that into your controller

Comment: check this answer and see if it is of use to you and your situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440653/unit-testing-with-httpcontext-application/36956967#36956967

Answer (score 1):

Use static property of `System.Web.HttpContext` class

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application`

Remember, that `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is available only in request-handling threads.

*Update*

Ah, mocking. Of course.

[HttpContextWrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if we use System.Web.HttpContext.Current in the controller class then we can't mock the HttpConted when we do the NUnit testing. So I need to use HttpContext.Application in the Controller and need to access the same in the Validate class also.How?

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this one: HttpContext is a class name, it is a static method

```
HttpContext.Current.Application
```