# Mocking HttpContext.Current Application does not persist

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, httpcontext

I am trying to set up unit testing on an existing solution which contains a MVC web project which uses an older 3rd party tool.  This tool makes heavy use of the `HttpContext.Current` to do the things it does, one of which is a fairly complex form of dependency injection to instantiate what are essentially service-layer objects.

So, in order to get these objects to instantiate in my unit testing project with everything they need I need to create my own `HttpContext` and assign it to `HttpContext.Current`.  I have this working relatively well but there seems to be a problem with the `HttpContext.Current.Application` object.  Basically, any time I add an object to that, either using `HttpContext.Current.Application[key] = object;` or `HttpContext.Current.Application.Add(key, object);` nothing seems to happen.

Decompiling `System.Web` indicates that there is not an easy way to assign the `Appplication` property since the getter is returning a value from a factory instance, so my guess is that this factory is generating a new application every time the `HttpApplication.Application` property is referenced.  Is there something I'm missing to ensure that this value is persistent?

Here is my code for creating the `HttpContext.Current` object:

```
internal static class UnitTestUtilities
{

    private static HttpApplication application;

    private static HttpContext GetHttpContext(string url)
    {
        if (application == null)
        {
            application = new HttpApplication();
            application.Init();
        }
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", url, ""),
            new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()))
        {
            ApplicationInstance = application
        };

        //Call hacks to get context application set up
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.SetContext(HttpContext.Current);
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.AddApplicationState(HttpContext.Current.Application);

        var testApplicationValue = "TEST";
        var testApplicationValue2 = "TEST2";
        HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
        HttpContext.Current.Application["TEST"] = testApplicationValue;
        HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("TEST2", testApplicationValue2);
        HttpContext.Current.Application.UnLock();

        //Issue is here: HttpContext.Current.Application still contains 0 items!

        return HttpContext.Current;
    }


    #region System.Web hacks
    private static void SetContext(this HttpApplication app, HttpContext context)
    {
        var prop = typeof(HttpApplication).GetField("_context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        prop.SetValue(app, context);
    }

    private static void AddApplicationState(this HttpApplication app, HttpApplicationState state = null)
    {
        if(state == null)
        {
            var ctor = typeof(HttpApplicationState).GetConstructor(
                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                      null, new Type[] { }, new ParameterModifier[] { });
            state = (HttpApplicationState)ctor.Invoke(new Object[] { });
        }
        var prop = typeof(HttpApplication).GetField("_state", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        prop.SetValue(app, state);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440653/unit-testing-with-httpcontext-application/36956967#36956967

Comment: @Nkosi I agree that this is not a great approach, but I have no control over the 3rd party code which is needed to properly instantiate the objects I need to unit test, and that code is directly referencing `HttpContext.Current.Application` and throwing errors if specific variables are not populated